# How to copy a file with unique name without navigating to directory?

Tags: filenames, command, cp, file-copy

Let's say I have a file with a unique name (e.g.*Screenshot20180509143013.png)* that I wish to copy to /media/SD256.

The file */media/drive1/Users/name/Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot20180509143013.png* is tangled in some sub-directory levels, and I wish not to navigate to */media/drive1/Users/name/Pictures/Screenshots/* to find that file with the unique name.

Instead, I wish to run a command while my working directory is /media/drive1/, which looks similar to:

```
copy --find-filename-then-copy Screenshot20180509143*3.png /dev/media/SD256/DestinationFolder
```

Is there such a command that can first find the file and then copy?

Comment: If any of the answers solved your problem, please [accept it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 15):

Using `find`:

```
find . -type f -name Screenshot20180509143013.png -exec cp {} /dev/media/SD256/DestinationFolder ';'
```

This would find all regular files in or below the current directory, whose names are exactly `Screenshot20180509143013.png`.  The found files would be copied to `/dev/media/SD256/DestinationFolder`.  If there are multiple files with the same name (which you say there aren't), the files would overwrite each other in the destination directory.

Comment: If the file is unique it would help to use the `-quit` action to tell `find` to stop the search once it found a result and performed the `-exec` action. Or is that a non-standard action?

Answer (score 14):

With `zsh` or `fish` or `ksh -o globstar` or `bash -O globstar` (or after `shopt -s globstar` in `bash`) or `tcsh` after `set globstar` or `yash -o extended-glob`:

```
cp -- **/Screenshot20180509143*3.png /dev/media/SD256/DestinationFolder
```

globstar, with the `**` syntax, does a recursive search; if the remainder of the glob (filename pattern) is unique, then you'll get the results you want. Note that I copied the `...3*3` from your example, and not the e.g. filename `Screenshot20180509143013.png` from earlier in the question.

Note that:

- `fish` and versions of bash prior to 4.3  will following symlinks when recursing. With `zsh`, `tcsh` or `yash`, you can use `***` instead of `**` to get that behaviour.
- `fish` will not find the file if it's in the current directory.
- Hidden files and files in hidden directories will not  be considered. Many shells have a `dotglob` option to reenable them. See also the `(D)` glob qualifier in `zsh`.
- In `zsh` you may also want to add `([1])` at the end of the pattern. `[1]` is a glob qualifier to copy only the *first* matching file.
- the `-i` option to `cp` can also guard against accidental overwrite if the file is found in several directories.

Answer (score 2):

#### ZSH

If you are using `zsh`, you can use `cp` with `zsh`'s globbing:

```
cp **/Screenshot20180509143013.png /dev/media/SD256/DestinationFolder
```

`**/Screenshot20180509143013.png` will try to find `Screenshot20180509143013.png` recursively from the current directory.

#### General purpose

For general purpose, you can always use `find` + `cp`:

```
cp "$(find ./ -type f -name "<picture_name>" )" "<destination>"
```

`find` - Search for a file.

`./` - Search in the current directory.

`-type f` - Limit the search for the regular files.

`-name "<picture_name>"` - Search for a file with name `<picture_name>`
(`*` in `<picture_name>` can be used to match any sequence)

`"$(find ./ -type f -name "<picture_name>" )"` - Replace this part of code with `stdout` of `find` command.

`cp "$(find ./ -type f -name "<picture_name>" )" <destination>` - Copy file with path gotten from `"$(find ./ -type f -name "<picture_name>" )"` to `<destination>`.

Comment: @Jeff Schaller Why would you edit it like this? It's uglier now :D

Comment: There were explicit file and directory names mentioned in the question, and using `<` and `>` as placeholders in shell commands _may_ me confusing.

Comment: Sorry about that; I believe it's more helpful to the asker to solve their problem directly. Feel free to revert the change if you don't like it.

Comment: Well, I tried to explain it a bit and that made it harder, but nevermind, thanks for the effort!

Comment: @Iskustvo Possible way to do it? Something like /path/to/file or /path/to/pattern (or whatever - I think you know what I'm trying to say). You could add something to it too: you give the general syntax like that but you also give an example with the precise name/glob/whatever?

Comment: @Pryftan I'm actually not sure that I understand what you are asking me. Do you want me to add example like `cp "$(find ./ -type f -name "Screenshot20180509143013.png" )" "/dev/media/SD256/DestinationFolder"`

Comment: @Iskustvo I mean instead of doing *`<filename>`* you could make it like it would be: a path (absolute or relative); same with a file glob. And since you wanted (I think) to include the actual file name given in the question you could *also give an example with that*. I'm not really asking you anything so much as saying another way to think about doing it if you feel *`<file>`* doesn't `cut` it.

Comment: @Iskustvo Right, I just reread. Part of that can be ignored then: obviously the *`-name`*  part of find isn't path. But I was more so saying you could have both: one to directly answer and one to give a more general example.

Comment: @Pryftan Thank you, I wanted to make ti general and give both, but the comment was edited by other users and there was already better answer than mine, so I've accepted that and didn't bother too much afterwards :D